# Updating multiple variables with case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two variables in *my_table*: *updated* and *status*. Each row has a unique *id*. For a given id='abc123', if the value of 'status' is 'AAA', I want to change *status* to 'BBB' and 'updated' to NOW(), and leave it unchanged otherwise.

I have an erroneous code:

```
UPDATE my_table set status=(CASE when status='AAA' THEN 'BBB'), 
SET updated=(CASE when status='AAA' THEN NOW()) where id='abc123';
```

How do I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is only slightly off, and there is nothing wrong with assigning a column to a `CASE` expression in an `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET
    status = CASE WHEN status = 'AAA' THEN 'BBB' ELSE status END,
    updated = CASE WHEN status = 'AAA' THEN NOW() ELSE updated END
WHERE id = 'abc123';
```

I added `ELSE` logic to your `CASE` expressions which default to not changing the value should the criteria fail.  You may remove them, but then non matches would receive `NULL` values, perhaps not what you intended.

Comment: Hey. Thanks! This works. I will accept this in 8 mins.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the else part. I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work.

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET STATUS = 'BBB',UPDATED =NOW()
    WHERE ID = 'ABC123' AND STATUS = 'AAA'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was aware of this. But, wanted one using case. Thanks for this anyway.